# Does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(n)}{\ln(n)}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

There's another post similar to mine that asks for what values of x $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos{xn}}{\ln{n}}}$ converges, but it gives no answer for the x=1 case, which I am concerned about.

My work was as follows

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\cos{n}}{\ln{n}}  \Longrightarrow \lim_{n\to\infty}{\bigg|\frac{\cos{(n+1)}}{\ln{(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{\ln{n}}{\cos{n}}}\bigg|  \overset{\text{As} \space n\to\infty}{\Longrightarrow}    \bigg|\frac{\cos{(n+1)}}{\cos{n}}\cdot\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{(n+1)}}\bigg|   \Longrightarrow   \bigg|\frac{\cos{n}\cos{1}-\sin{n}\sin{1}}{\cos{n}}\cdot\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{(n+1)}}\bigg|   \Longrightarrow  \bigg|(\frac{\cos{n}\cos{1}}{\cos{n}}-\frac{\sin{n}\sin{1}}{\cos{n}})\cdot\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{(n+1)}}\bigg|    \Longrightarrow   \bigg|(\cos{1}-\tan{n}\sin{1})\cdot\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{(n+1)}}\bigg|\space \space\space\bigg(\text{Note:}\space \lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{(n+1)}}}\to\frac{\infty}{\infty}\underset{\text{As}\space n\to\infty}{\overset{L'H}{\longrightarrow}}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n+1}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\to\frac{\infty}{\infty}\underset{\text{As}\space n\to\infty}{\overset{L'H}{\longrightarrow}}\frac{1}{1}=1\bigg)   \Longrightarrow   \bigg|(\cos{1}-\tan{n}\sin{1})\cdot1\bigg| \Longrightarrow 
  \cos1-\big|\lim_{n\to\infty}{\tan{n}}\big|\sin{1}\Longrightarrow    \boxed{\cos{1}-(DNE)\sin{1}}
$

Help me out please.

Comment: try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: Do you want to find out if the series converge or if it absolutely converge?

Comment: I guess both @user

Comment: The series converges but not absolutely.

Comment: @user can we determine if it absolutely converges by drichlet's test, if using the AST we can't omit the cos term because it's not strictly oscillating between -1 and 1

Answer (score 1):

The series converges (a) but not absolutely (b).

### (a)

The series converges by [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Indeed $b_n=\frac1{\ln n}$ is monotonically decreasing and $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n=0$ and for $a_n=\cos n$ we have:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^N\cos n=\Re \sum_{n=2}^N e^{in}=\Re\frac{e^{i(N+1)}-e^{i2}}{e^i-1}=
\frac{\sin(N+\frac12)-\sin\frac32}{2\sin\frac12}
$$
so that:
$$
\left|\sum_{n=2}^N a_n\right|\le\frac1{\sin\frac12}.
$$

### (b)

$$
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{|\cos n|}{\ln n}\ge\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{\cos^2 n}{\ln n}=
\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1+\cos 2n}{2\ln n}=\frac12\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{\ln n}+\frac12\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{\cos 2n}{\ln n}
$$
clearly diverges as it is larger than the sum of a divergent (left as exercise) and a convergent (cf. (a)) series.

Comment: Possible typo: Should $\dfrac{e^{i(N+1)}-e^{i2}}{1-e^i}$ be $\Re\dfrac{e^{i2}-e^{i(N+1)}}{1-e^i}$ ? The rest looks fine to me.

Comment: You still need to correct the sign. Please look at my comment again.

Comment: @JohnBentin Corrected.